# The + Possessive

Tags: definite-articles

I'm quite sure that I can say *the Onegin's score* meaning the opera “Eugene Onegin”. However, i feel that it's wrong to say *the Onegin's leg* meaning the character Eugene Onegin and that the correct form is *Onegin's leg*. Do I understand correct? Does that mean, that we can use *the + possessive* only if we talk about inanimated concepts?

Comment: No, you can't say *"the Onegin's score"*. Why do you think you can?

Comment: Peter Shor, thank you! Why is that? Can this rule be applied to any opera name or just to those named after characters?

Comment: You can say *"the Onegin score"*, *"the score of Onegin"*, or *"Onegin's score"*, but not *"the Onegin's score"*. This rule applies to any opera name. (And in fact, you can't put *"the"* before a possessive unless you can put *"the"* before the noun that possesses. That is, if you say *"the mother's name"*, you mean *"name of the mother"*, not *"the name of mother"*. So you can't say *"the Onegin's score"* because you can't say *"the Onegin"*.)

Comment: @PeterShor - What if the name of the work includes an article? Is _The Phantom's_ score correct?

Comment: If the name of the work includes an article, then you can include the article in the possessive. You can say *"The Phantom"*, so you can say *"The Phantom's* score".

Comment: But for some reason, when talking about Classical literature we do say “The Agamemnon” (for Aeschylus’s play “Agamemnon”) or “The Timaeus” (for Plato’s dialogue “Timaeus”). Why?

Comment: @fdb Do we? Do you have an example?

Comment: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+Agamemnon%2C+the+Timaeus&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20Agamemnon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20Timaeus%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I'm not sure if I've heard "the" before titles, but I've definitely heard it used before composer names. A conductor might say to his orchestra _tomorrow we're going to practice the Bach._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A phrase like "The somebody's thing" means that the 'thing' is owned by "The Somebody". The definite article is applying to 'somebody' not 'thing'.

So you can say "The President's leg", meaning a leg of "the President" (it's implied that there is only one president by the context). "The Onegin's Score" would have to be the score of "The Onegin", and since "The Onegin" shouldn't be used, the rest shouldn't either. The same applies to legs.

Correct English would be "The score of Onegin". or "The leg of Onegin"; also "Onegin's score" or "Onegin's leg". You can also say "The Onegin score", which may sound the same, meaning the score *called* Onegin.

If the definite article is part of the title, then you can say it - for example: "The Flying Dutchman's score".

Comment: DJClayworth, it was the clearest explanation I've ever heard. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In this case, "the Onegin" is not referring to a person. "Onegin" is an abbreviated form of the name of an opera, and the score belongs to the opera, not the titular character.

Comment: @BukvaCe You can show your appreciation by voting up and/or accepting the answer :-)